# ASP.NET MVC Print file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, printing

I have a button on my page and when the user clicks that,they should be able to print the document. the user sees the image format of the pdf file in the gallery view. How should  I handle the print for this document?

Comment: Do you want to print the current webpage or do you have a link on the page to a pdf file?

Comment: No ,I dont want to print the current web page. I have a pdf format for the image displayed, I want to print that PDF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did this by using jquery.click function on click of print button it fires
a window.open(here i called the asp.net webform page) which in the code behind
sets the response.contenttype to pdf and then the pdf document opens with the print
dialog open.